# I am trying to retrieve image from database to an imageview but getting this error,Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow

Tags: android, sqlite

This is my first time with `sqlite` database.I am trying to `retrieve` `image` from database to an `imageview` but getting this `error`,`Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow`.  Make sure the `Cursor` is initialized correctly before accessing `data` from it. Well its been a day and still no solution found.

Here is my `Activity` Code :

```
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = null;
    Cursor cursor=null;
    byte[] img = null;
    String tName =  metName.getText().toString();

    if(tName == null){
        Intent i = new Intent(this,PhotoLogin.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    try{
        dh = new DataBaseHelperWithPhoto(getApplicationContext());
        db = dh.getReadableDatabase();

        cursor = db.rawQuery("Select * from " + dh.TABLE_NAME_2 ,null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if(!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            do{
                img = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex("PHOTO"));
            }
            while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        else{
        }
        Bitmap bmp = getImage(img);
        mivPhoto.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My `DataBaseHelper.Class`:

```
public class DataBaseHelperWithPhoto extends SQLiteOpenHelper implements BaseColumns {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Employee.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "PICTURE";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME_2 = "USERPHOTO";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "ID";
    public static final String COLUMN_1_NAME = "NAME";
    public static final String PHOTO = "PH";

    public static final String TABLE_2 = "create table "
            + TABLE_NAME_2 + "(" + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + COLUMN_1_NAME + " string, "
            + PHOTO + " string) ";

    public DataBaseHelperWithPhoto(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
    {
        `db.execSQL(TABLE_2);`
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("Drop table if EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME_2);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Comment: see your `query`  u can assign photo as a `string` and u `get` the `image` as a `BLOB` fist u change this

Comment: @MohammadAli just because a column is defined with a type of string (*which actually has a type affinity of NUMERIC (see link)*) doesn't mean that you can't store a BLOB in that column in one or more rows, as per *Any column in an SQLite version 3 database, except an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column, may be used to store a value of any storage class (NULL, REAL, INTEGER, TEXT, BLOB).* [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your column names do not match:

```
public static final String PHOTO = "PH";
```

and

```
img = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex("PHOTO"));
```

Hence -1 is returned as column index.

Note that Android sqlite CursorWindow has an inherent max limit of 2MB per row so you should not be storing any "large data" in a column.

Answer (score 0):

In this line `img = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex("PHOTO"));` you are saying to get the column named PHOTO instead of the column named PH.

The `getColumnIndex` method returns -1 if the column cannot be found and there will never be a column with an offset of -1.

---

You could change the above line to

```
img = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex("PH")); //<<<< not the best way
```

Or more correctly change it to

```
img = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(PHOTO));
```

This result in the column name being resolved to **PH**

Comment: After doing these i am getting "Couldn't read row 0, col 2 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it."
What is it, am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Add line `Log.d("CSRINFO","Rows in Cursor = " + cursor.getCount() + " Columns in Cursor = " + cursor.getColumnCount());` Run and look for output in Log. My guess is that you have no rows in the cursor. So Row count would be 0. Have you inserted any rows? Add the line immediately after getting the Cursor from the rawQuery.